# jQuery is not defined in amplify.js package of Meteor 0.8.0.1

Tags: jquery, meteor, amplifyjs

In completely new **Meteor project with just amplify.js package** added, tehre is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: **jQuery is not defined amplify.js:830**

Any guesses what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I’d bet that jQuery is not defined in amplify.js on line 830.

Amplify.js is only used client-side, so you don’t need to use this apparently poorly-created package. Just create a folder in your project `client/lib/amplify/` and drop `amplify.min.js` in there. It will automatically get loaded and served client-side. It will also automatically be loaded *after* jQuery (which is loaded by Meteor core) and therefore jQuery will be defined on line 830.

Be warned though that a lot of the features that Amplify adds are duplicative of Meteor’s core functionality.

Comment: that's a working solution & thx for suggesting a correct location. I've reported this issue on [Meteor's GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2113). I just didn't understand why it isn't defined since as you mentioned, jQuery is loaded by Meteor core (beforehand, right?). Also, they've updated AmplifyJS from 1.1.0 to 1.1.2 about 2months ago, so I don't understand why they haven't tested one of official packages before updating.